# Why the constant of integration in pure inductive is zero, while deriving an expression for current?

Tags: current

I think it should not be zero but should depend on the physical quantities... Basically it should be circuit dependent

Comment: Can you give an example? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: When we derive the expression for current in the inductor

Comment: I assume you have an example problem you can show?

Comment: No it's the derivation

Comment: Wait I'll update the body of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't necessarily zero.

Consider this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvsldg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and assume the switch is closed for a long period of time, and then opened at t=0.

Then the initial current through the inductor is 10 mA, and this is also the "constant of integration" when writing an integral equation for the behavior for t > 0.

This does depend on the design of the circuit, but most importantly it depends on the history of the state of the circuit (whether switches have been opened or closed, whether voltage and current sources have changed their values, etc) for all the time before the instant we arbitrarily choose to call "t = 0".

Comment: OK.. That's what I was confused with.

Comment: I got the concept...

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessarily zero, though it's sometimes taken as zero in real conditions **after some time has passed**. That's why you will use 0 when deriving **steady-state** equations of normal circuits.

The boundary condition at t=0 is i(t) = C. In a typical (non-superconducting) inductor, resistance in the circuit and the inductor itself causes current to die off pretty rapidly, but if you start integrating when the current is not zero you'll have a constant term. For example, for a continuous mode switching power supply the integration over the switching cycle will have a constant of the inductor current \$i_0\$at the beginning of the cycle.

Comment: That means it is circuit dependent

Comment: Not sure what you mean by circuit-dependent- it's a mathematical relationship dependent on initial conditions, whatever the circuit is.